# text with adobe pdfmark not visible, why?

Tags: xml, pdf, header, adobe, ghostscript

my code in windows terminal:

```
gs -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress in.pdf pdfmark.txt
```

my text in pdfmark.txt

```
[/Subtype /FreeText
/Rect [ 0 135 500 535 ]
/Contents (tataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)
/ANN pdfmark
```

I like to add header to every single page, or replace an old one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the original file has been completely processed **before** the pdfmark is processed.

That means there is no 'current' page when you emit the pdfmark, so there is no page to attach it to.

The pdfmark operator is intended to be executed during the course of a PostScript program (it is, after all, a PostScript operator), you can't just execute it at random times and expect it to have any useful effect.

In the case of creating an annotation, you need to have a page 'current' when you execute the pdfmark. Your only likely method of doing this is to create a BeginPage or EndPage procedure and set this up **before** you start executing the PDF file.

The BeginPage and EndPage procedures are called at the start and end of every page, so at that point you still have a current page. Because you are (at this point) in the PostScript environment **and** have a current page, you can execute a pdfmark annotation and it will work.

So for example:

```
<<
/EndPage {
%% Check that this is for a showpage, not copypage or deactivation
  0 eq {
    pop %% discard the page number
    [/Subtype /FreeText
     /Rect [0 135 500 535]
     /Contents (Test)
     /ANN pdfmark
    true            
  }{
    pop
    false
  }ifelse
}
>> setpagedevice
```

Will put your pdfmark on every page. Instead of discarding the page number you could use it to take different actions on different pages.

Comment: okay thxs, so I see, it is only possible to set marks in pdf - not direkt in text. how can I do direkt text with right justify?! :-(

Comment: I don't really know what you are talking about here. If you want to modify an existing PDF file then Ghostscript is almost certainly not the right tool for the job, The way Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device works is described here (https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/VectorDevices.htm#Overview). Hopefully you can figure out from that whether what you want to do is possible or not. I'm guessing it isn't possible (or at least, not trivially possible) with pdfwrite.